# Using same Database of Username/Passwords for different applications?

Tags: database, mongodb, security, authentication

Is this ok to do, or is this generally discouraged? I am thinking of creating an app that does X, and has different users. After some time I want to write another app, which is very similar but different and enable all the users of the first app to login into the new App without having to sign up separately.

Answer (score 0):

How about a registration function like:

> "Enable Login for all Apps"

depending on which database you are using you can include the value in your database ( 1 = yes / 0 = no ) ... on login request for future apps, you implement a function where you check on that value in the database and allow / refuse the login with the old data...

(just a first thought on that) ... if you want to create a mobile app for like google play, please make sure, that you have clean code that handles the users data in a secure way and you have everything documented, how the users data is stored.

Good luck :)

Best Regards,
Sh0x